# Embedding/Integrating 3rd party editor in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pentaho, kettle

Is there any way to embed or integrate a 3rd party editor in eclipse. We are trying to add Kettle's Spoon editor (java based graphical interface for ETL) to eclipse, without modifying Spoon's code.
Is there a way to achive this.
The basic need is  - When user clicks on a Spoon file (*.ktr) then the Spoon editor opens up (along with all its menu and tool bar) in the editor pane of eclipse

Spoon is completely based on java and swt. Currently I am using Spoon as an external editor (through eclipse), but it opens up in separate window
Spoon : http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/.01+Introduction+to+Spoon

Kaushal

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Spoon besides the screenshots of it's GUI on it's website, so take the following with a grain of salt! (pun intended)

Most probably Spoon launches it's own [`Shell`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell.html), hence cannot be embedded in an editor pane.

Rather, to achieve your goal you will have to create your own editor and register it through the [`org.eclipse.ui.editors`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_editors.html) extension point.

The difficulty to create an editor depends on how modular Spoon is.